# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 / IIS Express and Windows Identity Foundation compatibility

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2010, wif

I'd like to install the SP in order to be able to use the IIS Express integration and IIS Express itself.

I have some Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) projects that we have developed.

Are there any gotchas with SP1 / WIF / IIS Express that anyone is aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been using this for a while and all seems OK.

Would be nice if IIS Express had a GUI though!